# Why isn't rxvt-unicode launching with perl extensions enabled by default even though I built it with '--enable-perl' and even '--enable-everything'?

Tags: windows, perl, cygwin, rxvt

I'm trying to get 'clipboard' perl extension for urxvt to work. I installed the script, it didn't work, and after some searching around I discovered that Cygwin's rxvt-unicode package is built with "--disable-perl" by default.

So I downloaded the source, changed it to "--enable-perl" and built/installed it. However, urxvt either stil doesn't seem to have perl extensions enabled when launched normally or the plugin 'clipboard' isn't being launched by default even though I've added

`URxvt.perl-ext-common: default,matcher,clipboard` to my .Xdefaults file.

Interestingly enough, the plugin works fine when I launch urxvt like this:

```
urxvt -pe clipboard
```

but I can't figure out if either perl extensions just aren't working from launch or the extension isn't working from launch, and why.

Here is the contents of my .Xdefaults file:

```
urxvt*font:             xft:gohufont:size=6
urxvt*boldFont:         xft:gohufont:size=6
urxvt*scrollBar:        false
urxvt*matcher.button:   1
urxvt.transparent:    false
urxvt*allow_bold:    true
urxvt.internalBorder: 15

Xft*dpi:                96
Xft*antialias:          true
Xft*hinting:            full

URxvt*geometry: 90x20
URxvt*fading:        0
URxvt*tintColor:     #ffffff
URxvt*shading:        0
URxvt*inheritPixmap:     False

URxvt.iso14755: false

URxvt*perl-lib: "C:\cygwin64\lib\urxvt\perl"
URxvt*perl-ext-common:  default,clipboard
URxvt*keysym.M-c:   perl:clipboard:copy
URxvt*keysym.M-v:   perl:clipboard:paste
URxvt*keysym.M-C-v: perl:clipboard:paste_escaped

URxvt*cursorBlink:                  true
URxvt*cursorUnderline:              true
URxvt*cursorColor:                  #ffffff
URxvt*scrollColor:                  #151515

*foreground:                         white
*background:                         #141115

!black
*color0:                             #3f3671
*color8:                             #514692
!red
*color1:                             #b52f43
*color9:                             #df3a53
!green
*color2:                             #91a7a7
*color10:                            #906b61
!yellow
*color3:                             #6c7f97
*color11:                            #b3b7c3
!blue
*color4:                             #3e456f
*color12:                            #59639f
!magenta
*color5:                             #6d577c
*color13:                            #9e7eb4
!cyan
*color6:                             #729392
*color14:                            #92bdbb
!white
*color7:                             #a9ac97
*color15:                            #e6eace
```

Comment: Updating the file doesn't immediately make the changes active. Did you run `xrdb -merge .Xdefaults`? Alternatively, you could also restart your X server. At any rate, if it worked, `xrdb -q` should show you the options you asked for.

Comment: @wouter-verhelst Yes, I have run `xrdb -merge .Xdefaults` and I have tried restarting my X server (Xming, specifically). `xrdb -q` shows my options correctly however the plugin still does not work by default. But the plugin does work when I launch urxvt through `urxvt -pe clipboard` as I mentioned before, which is odd.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I'm supposed to run `export DISPLAY=:0` before running `urxvt`, which I wasn't able to do since I made my Cygwin.bat file run urxvt directly. That explains why the extensions "weren't working".